# Use parameter values in Pig foreach

Tags: apache-pig

Is it possible to use parameter values in a Pig foreach generate?

Maybe something like this:

```
*%default TODAYS_DATE `date  +%Y/%m/%d`;
```

A = foreach lines generate line2, id, `$TODAYS_DATE` as line2, id, today;*

Or do I have to create a UDF that will append the current date to the schema instead?

Answer (score 1):

This should work. $VALUE will be substituted with whatever value you supply using `-param`.

e.g.

```
pig -param TODAYS_DATE=value myscript.pig
```

Comment: Remark: parameter substitution doesn't work in the Grunt shell (see PIG-2122)